# How can I move a QGraphicsItem using keyboard?

Tags: pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

Hello need help with moving an object in this case a qgraphicpixmapitem throw a scene using the keyboard. This is the code i have, what method do i need to add to handle the moving event?

thanks

```
class Object(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsFocusable, True)


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            print('right')
        elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            print('left')
        elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            print('down')
        elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            print('up')

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, e):
        pass


class Scene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the position of the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` on a `keyPressEvent`.

```
self.setPos(self.x()+my_x_offset, self.y()+my_y_offset)
```

replace `my_x_offset` and `my_y_offset` with appropriate numbers of you choosing (for instance for a left key press you might make `my_x_offset=10` and `my_y_offset=0`)